# Como puedo hacer una consulta y luego comparar los datos de esa consulta con mi variable de sesion

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo un método en el controlador para hacer una consulta a la tabla `Order` en la BD ahora necesito poder comparar el resultado de esos datos.

En la tabla `Order` tengo un columna llamada `IdUser` y lo quiero comparar con una variable de sesion `Session["UserID"]` que contiene el Id del usuario que ingreso al sistema.

Tengo esta idea:

```
public ActionResult GetAllOrders()
{
     BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNOrder = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
     List<Order> Ord = new List<Order>();
     Ord = _LNOrder.GetAllOrder();
     if ((int)Session["UserID"] == )
     {

     }
}
```

No se exactamente como comparar mi `Session["UserID"]` con el `IdUSer` de los datos de la consulta y si esta mal la manera en que lo hago.

Este es el medoto `GetAllOrder` que se comunica con el sp de la BD:

```
public List<Order> GetAllOrder()
    {
        List<Order> ord = new List<Order>();
        string sql = @"[spGetAllOrder]";
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = _MB.CreaDS(ds, "Order", sql, _CN);
            if (ds.Tables["Order"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["Order"].Rows)
                {
                    ord.Add(new Order()
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(item["Id"].ToString()),
                        User = new User() { Id = int.Parse(item["IdUser"].ToString()) },
                        Quantity = int.Parse(item["Quantity"].ToString()),
                        Total = decimal.Parse(item["Total"].ToString()),
                        Type = new Model.Type() { Id = int.Parse(item["IdType"].ToString()), Description = item["DescripType"].ToString() },
                        Status = new Status() { Id = int.Parse(item["IdStatus"].ToString()), Description = item["DescripStatus"].ToString() },
                        CreationDate = (item["CreationDate"].ToString() != "") ? DateTime.Parse(item["CreationDate"].ToString()) : DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900"),
                        ModificationDate = (item["ModificationDate"].ToString() != "") ? DateTime.Parse(item["ModificationDate"].ToString()) : DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900"),
                        CreatorUser = int.Parse(item["CreatorUser"].ToString()),
                        ModificationUser = int.Parse(item["ModificationUser"].ToString()),

                    });
                }
            }
            return ord;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Edite cosas en mi codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateOrder(DoorsxUser pDoorsxUser) //pDoorsxUser recibe los datos del producto que estoy creando para comprar
    {
            BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNOrder = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
            int userID = (int)Session["UserID"];
            int idU = userID;
            var orderList = _LNOrder.GetOrderByUser(idU);
            ViewBag.Listo = orderList; //aqui almacene lo que trajo la consulta
            foreach (Order item in ViewBag.Listo) //Aqui intento recorrer los datos de esa consulta
            {
                if (item.Status.Id == 1) //Comparo el estado de la orden "1" significa activa
                {
                    //Aqui debe ir el UpdateOrder
                }
                else 
                {
                    Order neworder = new Order()
                    {
                        User = new Model.User() { Id = userID },
                        Status = new Model.Status() { Id = 1 },
                        Type = new Model.Type() { Id = 1 },
                        Total = pDoorsxUser.Quantity * 100,
                        Quantity = pDoorsxUser.Quantity,
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatorUser = userID,
                        ModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        ModificationUser = userID
                    };

                    int NEWord = _LNOrder.InsertOrder(neworder);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Luego de que se almacenan los datos en el `ViewBag.Listo` se salta todo lo demas.

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener de la tabla `Order` la orden que tenga el Id del usuario(eso ya esta),si existe y esta activa quiero que modifique la orden que existe con el id del usuario, si la orden no esta activa o si no existe que cree una nueva orden con el id de ese usuario.

Comment: ¿Pdemos ver el contenido del método GetAllOrder?, para entonces direccionarte donde poner este filtro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `GetAllOrder()` devuelve todas las ordenes de la db, lo primero que deberias evaluar es si usar este es correcto o si deberias crear un `GetById()` y pasarle por parametro el id que tienes en la session para poder aplicarlo al `WHERE` del `SELECT` usando la consulta

```
SELECT * FROM Order WHERE IdUser = @IdUser
```

Ahora bien sino quieres hacer eso y segyir usando `GetAllOrder()` entonce spuede aplicar el filtro en memoria con la ayuda de linq

```
public ActionResult GetAllOrders()
{
    int userId = (int)Session["UserID"];

     BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNOrder = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
     List<Order> orderList = _LNOrder.GetAllOrder();

     List<Order> orderByUser = orderList.Where(x=> x.UserID == userId).ToList();

     return Ok(orderByUser);
}
```

no hace falta compararlo en el `if` porque ya lo filtras en el `Where()` de linq, con este obtienes la entidad de la lista que coincide la propiedad userid

Comment: Me faltaba algo como esto `int userId = (int)Session["UserID"];`. Probe tu codigo y efectivamente funciona, en mi pregunta tenia la condicion If es porque necesito hacer algo luego de comparar esos datos

Comment: Y tal como dices al inicio, tengo un `GetOrderById` pero cree uno nuevo que llame  `GetOrderByUser` en estos momentos estoy probando.

Porque lo que necesito hacer es comprar si existe una orde con el ID del usuario, si existe pues modifico la orden con cosas nuevas, en caso de no existir creo una nueva orden

Answer (score 0):

Al final hice esto, lo dejo por si le sirve de guia a alguien mas, quizas se un poco confuso o haya mejores maneras de realizarlo pero puede servir de idea:

```
/*Este es el metodo que llamo para modificar la orden
cuando se esta creando una nueva puerta */

[HttpPost]      
    public ActionResult UpdateOrderExist(Order item, DoorsxUser pDoorsxUser)
    {
        BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNUPor = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
        item.Quantity = item.Quantity + pDoorsxUser.Quantity;
        item.Total = item.Total + pDoorsxUser.SubTotal;
        return Json(_LNUPor.UpdateOrder(item));
    }

/*Primero pasa por este metodo compara si existe una orden para el usuario logueado
si no existe le crea y crea la nueva puerta, si exixte y esta activa modifica la
orden, llama al metodo de arriba para eso y luego vuelve para crear la puerta,
y si exste una orden pero la orden no esta activa (ya fue procesada) crea una nueva
orden activa */

    public ActionResult InsertDoorsxUser(DoorsxUser pDoorsxUser)
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNOrder = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
            int userID = (int)Session["UserID"];
            int idU = userID;
            var orderList = _LNOrder.GetOrderByUser(idU);
            ViewBag.Listo = orderList;
            Order item = ViewBag.Listo;
            if (item.Status == null)
            {
                Order neworder = new Order()
                {
                    User = new Model.User() { Id = userID },
                    Status = new Model.Status() { Id = 1 },
                    Type = new Model.Type() { Id = 1 },
                    Quantity = pDoorsxUser.Quantity,
                    Total = pDoorsxUser.SubTotal,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatorUser = userID,
                    ModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModificationUser = userID
                };

                int IdOrder = _LNOrder.InsertOrder(neworder);
                neworder.Id = IdOrder;
                pDoorsxUser.CreatorUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.Order = neworder;
                pDoorsxUser.User.Id = idU;
                BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser();

                return Json(_LN.InsertDoorsxUser(pDoorsxUser));
            }
            else if (item.Status.Id == 1)
            {
                UpdateOrderExist(item, pDoorsxUser);

                pDoorsxUser.CreatorUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.Order = item;
                pDoorsxUser.User.Id = idU;

                BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser();

                return Json(_LN.InsertDoorsxUser(pDoorsxUser));
            }
            else if (item.Status.Id == 2)
            {
                Order neworder = new Order()
                {
                    User = new Model.User() { Id = userID },
                    Status = new Model.Status() { Id = 1 },
                    Type = new Model.Type() { Id = 1 },
                    Quantity = pDoorsxUser.Quantity,
                    Total = pDoorsxUser.SubTotal,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatorUser = userID,
                    ModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModificationUser = userID
                };

                int IdOrder = _LNOrder.InsertOrder(neworder);
                neworder.Id = IdOrder;
                pDoorsxUser.CreatorUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationUser = userID;
                pDoorsxUser.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
                pDoorsxUser.Order = neworder;
                pDoorsxUser.User.Id = idU;
                BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser();

                return Json(_LN.InsertDoorsxUser(pDoorsxUser));
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
```